# How to get hours and minutes in desired timezone without creating new moment object?

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I have to display a string on the web page in this format: `16:00 HH:mm`

I'm using a moment object to represent a date/time and timezone.

```
var day = moment().tz('GMT');
day.hours(16).minutes(0).seconds(0).milliseconds(0);
```

So this is 16:00 in GMT time.

On my web page I want to change the time zone and then collect the hours and minutes.

If I make a new moment object

```
var day2 = moment().tz('PST); //this is 8 AM since gmt was 16
console.log(day2.get('hours'));
```

it is 16 not 8!

and try to get the hours and minutes they are in GMT not in PST.

How can I get it in PST? Do I have to keep wrapping it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
// initialize a new moment object to midnight UTC of the current UTC day
var m1 = moment.utc().startOf('day'); 

// set the time you desire, in UTC
m1.hours(16).minutes(0);

// clone the existing moment object to create a new one
var m2 = moment(m1);   // OR  var m2 = m1.clone();   (both do the same thing)

// set the time zone of the new object
m2.tz('America/Los_Angeles');

// format the output for display
console.log(m2.format('HH:mm'));
```

[Working jsFiddle here.](https://jsfiddle.net/zs6dncu0/)

If you can't get it to work, then you haven't correctly loaded moment, moment-timezone, and the required time zone data.  For the data, you either need to call `moment.tz.add` with the zone data for the zones you care about, or you need to use one of the moment-timezone-with-data files available on the site.

In the fiddle, you can see the moment-files I'm loading by expanding the External Resources section.

[image: fiddle resources]

Comment: Also, I may have misinterpreted part of your question in that you don't *need* to clone the moment if you don't want to.  If you're fine with `m1` changing, then you don't need to create `m2`.

Answer (score 1):

PST can mean different things in different regions. In the moment-timezone docs, I see nothing referring to "PST" or similar abbreviations.

Perhaps try:

```
var day2 = moment().tz('PST'); 
// 16 with Error: Moment Timezone has no data for PST. See http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/data-loading/.

var day2 = moment().tz('America/Los_Angeles'); 
// 15
```

Comment: are you getting an error in your console when using PST?

Comment: Nope. Even with America/Los_Angeles the hour is wrong.

Comment: If you're just trying to output a representation of the date, try using the format() method instead.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about using moment.js, but it's fairly simple using POJS and the same algorithm should work. Just subtract 8 hours from the UTC time of a date object and return a formatted string based on the adjusted UTC time.

Assuming PST is "Pacific Standard Time", also known as "Pacific Time" (PT), and is UTC -8:00:

```js
/* @param {Date} date - input date object
** @returns {string} - time as hh:mm:ss
**
** Subtract 8 hours from date UTC time and return a formatted times string
*/
function getPSTTime(date) {
  var d = new Date(+date);
  d.setUTCHours(d.getUTCHours() - 8);
  return ('0' + d.getUTCHours()).slice(-2) + ':' +
         ('0' + d.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2) + ':' +
         ('0' + d.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);
}

document.write('Current PST time: ' + getPSTTime(new Date));
```

There is [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) which adds functionality to moment.js for [IANA time zones](https://www.iana.org/time-zones). For PST you can use America/Los_Angeles, however it might also automatically adjust for daylight saving so you'll get PDT when that applies. If you want ignore daylight saving, use the above or find a location with the offset you need and use that.

Comment: This will work in the case where you ignore DST and use -8 year round.  It's nice clean code actually.  However, it doesn't reflect reality since Pacific time uses -7 for daylight saving time.  PDT is actually a larger part of the year now than PST!  :D  Most of the time, I find that when people say "PST", they mean "US Pacific Time".  In my experience, it's actually quite rare to want to use PST without taking PDT into consideration.  There are a couple of zones like `America/Metlakatla` and `Pacific/Pitcairn` that do that, but that's about it.  I'd love to hear if you know otherwise.

Comment: @MattJohnson—yes. The OP only mentioned PST, hence my comments on daylight saving. I'm not a fan of using Date client side for any serious date manipulation, it's just not reliable (well, it's reliably borked).